# How to send XML data to Flask backend using JS

Tags: javascript, ajax, flask, request, xmlhttprequest

I want to send some part of a webpage as an XML document to my Flask backend using JS:

I've tried sending it using this JavaScript code:

```
  function sendData() {
    let data = document.getElementById("tableID");
    console.log(data);
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("POST", "app.py", true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    xhr.send(JSON.stringify(data));
    console.log(xhr);
  }
```

but didn't get a response from the backend:

```
@app.route('/validate', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def validate():
    tracks = observed_tracks(get_tracks())
    if request.method == "POST":
        print("submitted......")
    return render_template("tools/validate.html", tracks=tracks)
```

The data sent looks like this (this is just a sample, the data is dynamically generated):

```
<table id="tableID">
    <tbody>
    <tr class="adminToolsLine">
          <td class="adminToolsBox1" type="text" name="Artist" id="Artist"> Artist02 </td>
          <td class="adminToolsBox1" type="text" name="Album" id="Album">ALbum f Artist02 </td>
          <td class="adminToolsBox2" type="text" name="Track" id="Track"> ihnj </td>
          <td class="adminToolsBox3" type="text" name="Genre" id="Genre"> Indie </td>
          <td class="adminToolsBox4" type="text" name="Length" id="Length"> 9:32 </td>
          <td class="adminToolsBox1" type="text" name="Infos" id="Infos"> injojn k </td>
          <td class="adminToolsBox0Line" onclick="removeParent(this)">X</td>
        </tr>
      <tr class="adminToolsLine">
          <td class="adminToolsBox1" type="text" name="Artist" id="Artist"> testgenreMenu </td>
          <td class="adminToolsBox1" type="text" name="Album" id="Album"> testgenreMenu </td>
          <td class="adminToolsBox2" type="text" name="Track" id="Track">track01_testgenre </td>
          <td class="adminToolsBox3" type="text" name="Genre" id="Genre"> Folk </td>
          <td class="adminToolsBox4" type="text" name="Length" id="Length"> 02:00 </td>
          <td class="adminToolsBox1" type="text" name="Infos" id="Infos"> shouldbefolk </td>
          <td class="adminToolsBox0Line" onclick="removeParent(this)">X</td>
        </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Do you have any idea of what should I change to the back end or to the JS to make it work ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your JS function, you are trying to send a POST request to a python file (app.py), but what you need to do is send a POST request to a route - a flask route that you have in your app.py file. So you need to specify the desired route as a parameter in your POST request.

If you check the documentation for [XMLHttpRequest()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/open), you will see that the the xhr.open() method takes "URL" is a parameter.

You haven't provided a URL, you provided a python file.

So,

```
xhr.open("POST", "app.py", true);
```

should be

```
xhr.open("POST", "/validate", true);
```

Comment: While this code may resolve the OP's issue, it is best to include an explanation as to how your code addresses the OP's issue. In this way, future visitors can learn from your post, and apply it to their own code. SO is not a coding service, but a resource for knowledge. Also, high quality, complete answers are more likely to be upvoted. These features, along with the requirement that all posts are self-contained, are some of the strengths of SO as a platform, that differentiates it from forums. You can edit to add additional info &/or to supplement your explanations with source documentation.

Comment: @ysf Great reminder, thank you. I have edited the post to make it more complete.